# How to disable localization warnings for some ui elements in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I develops multilingual iOS project that has translations for UI elements in `%LANG%.lproj/%STORYBOARD_NAME%.strings`:

```
/* Class = "UINavigationItem"; title = "User information"; ObjectID = "yXU-vS-01l"; */
"yXU-vS-01l.title" = "User information";
```

When UI element has no translation, Xcode writes warning in console:

```
Localizable string "yXU-vS-01l.title" not found in strings table "Main" of bundle CFBundle  (executable, loaded).
```

But some elements get its values at runtime only and doesn't need storyboard translations.

How can I disable warnings for such elements?
Now I see two ways:

1. Set localizable value as empty string
   It helps with navigation items or other elements with visible bounds, but elements as labels and buttons will be invisible in design-time and also can be resize to zero-width
2. Add dummy translations to `*.strings` files
   Will be too timespently when number of supporting languages will increase

May be another way exists? Eg set some property for UI element?

Answer (score 0):

It's Xcode 10.2 now and I think in order to get rid of those warnings You should disable "Localization Debugging" in "Edit Scheme" -> "Options" for this target.